# Trying to display a list of youtube videos into django template with django-embed-video

Tags: python, django, video, youtube, embed

I am trying to embed a list of youtube videos, in which more videos will be added over time, into my django app using django-embed-video. Going after their documentation I did the following:

models.py

```
from embed_video.fields import EmbedVideoField

class Youtube(models.Model):
    video = EmbedVideoField()
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, db_index=True, unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.video
```

admin.py

```
from .models import Youtube
from embed_video.admin import AdminVideoMixin

class YoutubeAdmin(AdminVideoMixin, admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('video', 'slug')

admin.site.register(Youtube, YoutubeAdmin)
```

views.py

```
from .models import Youtube

def display_video(request):
    videos = Youtube.objects.all()
    context = {'videos': videos}
    return render (request, 'scienceblog/post/videos.html', context)
```

videos.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load embed_video_tags %}
{% video item.video 'small' %}

{% block content %}

{% if videos %}

    {% for v in videos %}
    {{ v }}
    {% endfor %}

    {% else %}
    <p>No videos yet</p>

{% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

Everything works perfect in the admin site. The youtube links are added and the videos are displayed. However I am very unsure about the HTML tags. The browser only displays the youtube links as a string when videos.html is rendered. How can I display the videos?

Answer (score 4):

Thanks for the quick answer raratiru! It brought me on the idea to look into the code of the django-embed-video app itself. I fiddled around with it a bit and now it works just how I wanted it to work. The relevant code is:

videos.html

```
{% load embed_video_tags %}
{% for v in videos %}
    {% video v.video as my %}
        <iframe width="{{ 480 }}" height="{{ 320 }}" src="{{ my.url }}" 
        frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    {% endvideo %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Having gained some reputation, [you may accept your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) to show that the question is answered, and upvote the ones that helped.

Answer (score 1):

You need to acquire the `EmbedVideoField()` which is `video` according to `models.py`. Therefore, the loop should read something like:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load embed_video_tags %}
{% video item.video 'small' %}

{% block content %}

{% if videos %}

    {% for v in videos %}
    {{ v.video }}
    {% endfor %}

    {% else %}
    <p>No videos yet</p>

{% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

It is possible that the `EmbedVideoField()` has more attributes that have to be accessed, you have to check the relevant docs. For example, if the embed code is stored in `EmbedVideoField().embed_code` you can reach it as such:

```
{% for v in videos %}
{{ v.video.embed_code }}
{% endfor %}
```